# Qt Parseo de un Json (objeto dentro de un array)

Tags: c++, json, qt

Tengo el siguiente json

```
{
   "Perfiles":   [{

        "Nombre":"Default",
        "E/S": {
            "EntradaHr": 6.45,
            "SalidaHr": 12.15
        }

    }] 
}
```

Y el siguiente codigo

```
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QFile>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QFile jsonFile("miJson.json");
    jsonFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
    QByteArray jsonFileData = jsonFile.readAll();
    jsonFile.close();

    QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonFileData);
    QJsonObject object = document.object();

    QJsonValue value = object.value("Perfiles");
    qDebug() << "Value => " << value;

    QJsonArray array = value.toArray();
    qDebug() << "Array => " << array;

    QJsonObject e_sObj = object["E/S"].toObject();
    qDebug() << "E/s Object => " << e_sObj;
    qDebug() << "Object value => " << object.value("E/S");

    auto entradaHr = e_sObj["EntradaHr"];
    qDebug() << "Hora entrada => " << entradaHr;

    return 0;
}
```

No puedo acceder al objeto `E/S`

```
    "E/S": {
        "EntradaHr": 6.45,
        "SalidaHr": 12.15
    }
```

Mi pregunta es como podria acceder a el?

Comment: "*No puedo acceder al objeto `E/S`*" eso no ayuda a que deduzcamos el problema que te encuentras. ¿Qué sucede al acceder al archivo? ¿Qué datos de salida obtienes? ¿Has probado poniendo el `close()` al final? ¿Has comprobado si el archivo está abierto o ha dado fallos al abrir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás entendiendo la estructura de JSON:

```
{
   "Perfiles":   [{

        "Nombre":"Default",
        "E/S": {
            "EntradaHr": 6.45,
            "SalidaHr": 12.15
        }

    }] 
}
```

En JSON, los arrays se delimitan con corchetes `[]` y los objetos con llaves `{}`. En este caso, `Perfiles` es un **array de objetos**, por eso tiene una llave dentro de los corchetes. Tu te estás saltando toda esta estructura e intentas acceder a `E/S` como si la clave estuviese a la altura de `Perfiles`:

```
QJsonObject object = document.object(); // object es el objeto raiz

QJsonValue value = object.value("Perfiles"); // Recuperas la clave Perfiles
qDebug() << "Value => " << value;

QJsonArray array = value.toArray();
qDebug() << "Array => " << array;

QJsonObject e_sObj = object["E/S"].toObject(); // E/S tambien en el raiz????
```

Como te he comentado, tienes que convertir el primer elemento del array en un objeto y después inspeccionar dicho objeto:

```
QJsonObject primerPerfil = array.at(0).toObject();
QJsonObject e_sObj = primerPerfil.value("E/S").toObject();
```

Una vez hecho esto, para recuperar los valores de entrada y salida hay que actuar sobre `e_sObj`, no sobre `objeto` (que recordemos representa a la raiz del JSON):

```
qDebug() << "Entrada => " << e_sObj.value("EntradaHr").toDouble();
qDebug() << "Salida  => " << e_sObj.value("SalidaHr").toDouble();
```

Comment: Gracias, basicamente yo sabia que tenia que ingresar a traves del array pero no lograba como. Lograste despejar ciertas duda :)